# Concatenation not working in if expression (inline if-else) with Jinja2 on Ansible

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2, templating, ansible-template

So, I'm trying to create a sort of multiple alternative variable thing in Jinja and since this

```
{{ var1.x | var2.x | default('', true) }}
```

does not work, since var2 is not a filter...

I am using inline if expressions like so

```
{{ var1.x if var1.x is defined else var2.x | default('', true) }}
```

to achieve that. But now I want to concatenate a string to both vars but not the default value, so I tried to do this

```
{{ var1.x ~ '-' if var1.x is defined else var2.x ~ '-' | default('', true) }}
```

but the concatenation in the else is not allowed for some reason, as Ansible outputs an error from it! -vvv gives no extra info.

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'x'
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'x'"}
```

But if I do this

```
{{ var1.x ~ '-' if var1.x is defined else var2.x | default('', true) }}
```

it works... Why? And how can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I tested `{{ var1 ~ '-' if var1 is defined else var2 ~ '-' | default('', true) }}` and it works fine, your issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: I am using Ansible to fill the template, maybe it's a problem there? Thanks

Comment: Yes this was working in pure jinja2 but not in ansible. Glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem is very easy to fix...

I did not think that you could chain inline if expressions in Jinja like you can in almost all programming languages...

My problem is fixed by:

```
{{ var1.x ~ '-' if var1.x is defined else var2.x ~ '-' if var2.x is defined | default('', true) }}
```

Thanks to @Rivers who made me look elsewhere for bugs, which actually made me realize that the error message was correct and I was just being foolish